# How to count aggregate query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm building pagination with mongoose/nodejs application and have the following code:

```
var Query = Model.find(   
  "location": {
     "$geoWithin": {
        "$box": [
           [165.8694369, -52.61941849999999],
           [175.831536, -29.2313419]
         ]
     }
  }
});

// Get count of documents
return Query.count(function (err, totalCount) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // Get paginated list
    return Query.
          find().
          skip(skip).
          limit(limit).
          exec(function (err, results) {
             if (err) throw err;

             // return result 
          });
```

In the preceding code I get `totalCount` to build pagination on client-side and it works fine. But now I need to use `aggregate` instead `find` and trying the following:

```
// Construct pipeline
var pipeline = [{
   "$geoNear": {
      "near": [165.8694369, -52.61941849999999],
      "distanceField": "distance"
    }
}];

var Query = adModel.aggregate(pipeline);

// Get count of documents
return Query.count(function (err, totalCount) {
    if (err) throw err;
```

But unfortunately I get the error `count() method does not exists`. How could I total count of documents with aggregation framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [Model.aggregate doesn't return a Query object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) that's why the `count` method does not exists.

Anyway since it returns a promise you can count your docs like this:

```
adModel.aggregate(pipeline).then(function (docs) {
    console.log(docs.length);
});
```

and if you don't like promises you can still pass a callback:

```
adModel.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs.length);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but `Model.count()` is more efficient is it? In your snippet we execute `aggregate` twice and it could be not efficient.

Comment: @Erik nope, they are just two ways to call it. The first one use promises the second one uses a casllback. You don't need to use both of them, just one depending if you want to use promises or callbacks

Comment: This doesn't help if you want to know the *total* number of documents against a query, and then only load a subset of documents, for pagination purposes. Can you determine the total count (e.g. before the `$limit` stage) without running the aggregation query twice?